# Error Creating Table: "There is already an object named 'table' in the database", but I have no constraint with that name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Error occur in **MS SQL Server**

```
Error Creating Table: "There is already an object named 'table' in the database", but I have no table and not any constraint with the same name in database.
```

I have to inform you that this happened after performing a rename on a table and then a creation of a table named with the old table name.

Example:

```
sp_rename OldTable, NewTable
Create Table [OLDTable] ([id] [int] Identity(1,1) NOT NULL)
```

And then it gives me the error

If someone knows the answer, I've been searching for hours and I would be glad to solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe a view, synonym or a custom data type?

Comment: could this be the identity constraint that is the same name?

Answer (score 4):

Try `SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name LIKE '%yout_table_name%'` to see all existing system objects with given name.

Comment: There is ton of results containing 'mytablename' but no results having only the specified name.

Answer (score 0):

Try running code below before creating table .  You might get lucky.

```
DROP TABLE <tablename>
```

Sure, you'll never really know what happened...

Comment: Already tried that, see what it did: Cannot drop the table 'TableName', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.